# AzureDevOps iOS build fastlane use Apple API Key

Tags: ios, azure-devops, app-store-connect

I've created an Azure DevOps pipeline for building a React Native mobile application for iOS. I have a service connection to Apple's App Store Connect and it uploads the build to TestFlight as expected. I am also passing Release Notes to the AppStoreRelease task and this requires FastLane credentials to get around the Two Factor Authentication.

I tried the approach of creating a fastlane session ID locally and putting that onto the service connection as per https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/README.md#support-for-ci-machines. This approach works fine but the session times out and it has to be done again which isn't a sustainable approach.

I've seen documentation on using App Store Connect keys to authenticate (https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/), but haven't seen any documentation on how to do this for Azure DevOps. Has anyone done this and can provide documentation or a point in the right direction.

Comment: We could create the fastlane session token by following these [instructions](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#use-of-application-specific-passwords-and-spaceauth) and set this value on the Apple App Store service connection.

Comment: I've tried that, but the token seems to expire within a day. It isn't a good solution to have to refresh the token manually everyday. It feels like there has to be a better (more sustainable) approach.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now?

Comment: Hi Carlos. Yes it is, or rather we have given up on stopped trying to send across release notes / testing notes. Which is a real disappointment and annoyance

Comment: Hi, I also retested but just found the workaround I shared before.